# R igraph: Estimation of edge betweenness centrality only possible for small cutoff values

Tags: r, igraph

I have an R `igraph` object with approximately 5000 vertices and 13000 edges representing an urban road network. As I am interested in the edge betweenness centrality for all edges, I used the function `estimate_edge_betweenness()` with different cutoff values. However, this works only for cutoff values smaller than 70. Using larger values results in the following:

> "Error in estimate_edge_betweenness(graph, cutoff = 70) :
> At stack.pmt:193 : stack push failed, Out of memory"

Regardless of which cutoff value would be useful for my specific application, I do not understand the reasons for this error. When I generate a random graph with the same (or even a much larger) number of vertices and edges, the estimation works, also for much larger cutoff values. This indicates that the structure of the graph is of great importance here. Since I have little knowledge of graphs and the corresponding algorithms, I have no idea what is going on here.

So my questions: Does anyone have an idea what might be the causes for the above mentioned phenomenon?